# linking error trying to use SwiftUI - Undefined symbol: _swift_getOpaqueTypeConformance

Tags: ios, swiftui

I'm trying to add some SwiftUI, conditionally on devices (running iOS 13) that support it, as the deployment target for my iOS app is iOS 12.0. I'm using Xcode 11.3.1.

My code that conditionally presents a SwiftUI view (embedded in a UIHostingController) is wrapped in `if #available(iOS 13.0, *) {`, and my SwiftUI view is prefixed with `@available(iOS 13.0, *)`.

As the name of the undefined symbol (`_swift_getOpaqueTypeConformance`) suggests, the problem is related to declaring the my SwiftUI body return type as `some View` - and I get this linking error with the default "Hello World" code Xcode generates when I create a new SwiftUI file.

However, if I change my SwiftUI view to not take advantage of opaque declarations and change my body type to `var body: Text`, the view builds and runs as expected.

I would seem to be building with incompatible Swift versions; but the version I think I need for opaque return types is Swift 5.1. I believe Xcode 11.3.1 provides Swift 5.1.3, and in fact I confirmed that from the command line via `swift --version`. In my project settings, I have **Swift Language Version = Swift 5**.

Any idea what could make the linker unable to locate this symbol?

Comment: Would you prepare reproducible example?

Comment: Please have a read of [mcve] and update your question

Comment: I got the same error after adding a widget extension to my react-native project